# Taking record from Excel and searching multiple records in .csv/.txt file using vba

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am looping through Excel (for example record city ="Paris") and then want to retrieve multiple records from .csv files (there could be possibility of retrieving multiple records available in .csv files pertaining to city paris)

Here is be basic structure of .txt which tab delimited file.

```
1 Tokyo JA  test    Tokyo   "test, testttttttttt."  "images url to download delimited by ,"
2 Tokyo JA  test    Tokyo   "test, testttttttttt."  "images url to download delimited by ,"
3 Paris FR  test    Tokyo   "test, testttttttttt."  "images url to download delimited by ,"
```

Can anybody help me with this, please note that above file is .txt file and having said that I want to know how many records are ( count ) met with per Excel records in the .txt/csv file so I want to do other activities required in my system.

Here is my code :

```
currPath1 = "C:\sourceexcel.xlsx"
    currentPath2 = "C:\CSVtoberead.txt"
fileNum =FreeFile()
    Open currentPath2 For Input As fileNum
    totoalRows= xlsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        startrow1 =1
        PreviousCity=""
        For x= startRow To totoalRows
            currentCity = xlsheet.Cells(startRow,3 ).value  '' this is city from excel sheet
            Do While Not EOF( fileNum )
                Line Input #fileNum, txt  '''file to read .txt file
                parseRecord = Split (txt,Chr(9))
                If  parserecord(1)= currentCity Then
```

Comment: You've said what you want to do but failed to ask any question. What technical difficulty is preventing you from fulfilling your desires? What have you tried so far? You tend to get better answers if you include your code (even if the code is buggy). As your question stands, it seems like you want to use Stack Overflow as a free coding service, which isn't how it works.

Comment: currPath1 = "C:\test1.xlsx"
currentPath2 = "C:\output-Cities.txt"                                             totoalRows= xlsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 startrow1 =1
 PreviousCity=""
 For x= startRow To totoalRows
  currentCity = xlsheet.Cells(startRow,3 ).value
  Do While Not EOF( fileNum )
   Line Input #fileNum, txt                                                                     from above code I never knew that how many records are matched per city records from excel sheet. so my question is that is there any other way to play around.

Comment: That helps -- but please put the code in your question rather than a comment, and please give a little more context. As it stands, you have fragments of loops and a host of undeclared variables.

Comment: Are those spaces (outside of the quoted strings) supposed to be tabs? In the line which starts "1 Tokyo" -- is there a tab before that Tokyo, or is the first tab before the second Tokyo in the line (which is how it looks, but then it wouldn't be a simple tab-delimited file).

Comment: 1 tab tokyo, hope that helps, also whereever it starts with "" and ends with quota those are multiple values .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the text file repeatedly, once for every occurrence of a city in your worksheet, is quite inefficient. Instead, you could read the file just once, loading the data in each line into a dictionary which is keyed by the cities and whose values are collections of arrays (each array corresponding to a split of a line). Something like this:

```
Function ExtractData(fname As String, colNumber As Long, Optional delim As String = vbTab) As Variant
    'Takes a delimited txt file and returns a dictionary
    'keyed by the entries in the specified column
    'the values for a key is a collection of split lines

    Dim fileNum As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim C As Collection
    Dim d As Variant, k As Variant, parseRecord As Variant

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open fname For Input As fileNum

    Do While Not EOF(fileNum)
        Line Input #fileNum, txt  '''file to read .txt file
        parseRecord = Split(txt, delim)
        k = parseRecord(colNumber)
        If d.exists(k) Then
            d(k).Add parseRecord
        Else
            Set C = New Collection
            C.Add parseRecord
            d.Add k, C
        End If
    Loop

    Close #fileNum

    Set ExtractData = d

End Function
```

You should be able to use the above function to streamline your code. To give you some idea of how it works, I copied your data (with the spaces replaced by tabs) into a text file and ran:

```
Sub test()
    Dim v As Variant
    Set v = ExtractData("C:/Programs/test.txt", 1)
    Debug.Print v("Tokyo").Count
    Debug.Print v("Paris").Count
    Debug.Print Join(v("Tokyo")(2), "/")
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
2 
1 
2/Tokyo/JA/test/Tokyo/"test, testttttttttt."/"images url to download delimited by ,"
```

Expanding a bit: run the function just once, at the beginning of your code, and assign it to a variable (e.g. `v`). Then iterate through the column of the spreadsheet which contains the cities. For each city, `v.Exists(city)` can check if the city occurs in the data. If it does, then `v(city).Count` will tell you how many times, and things like `v(city)(i)` can be used to access the individual lines of data that correspond to that city. If `j` is a specific column number then `v(city)(i)(j)` will give (as a string) the data in column j of occurrence i of the given city.

Comment: thanks a lot  John Coleman for your help, can you please help me understanding below code :  If d.exists(k) Then
            d(k).Add parseRecord
        Else
            Set C = New Collection
            C.Add parseRecord
            d.Add k, C
        End If

Comment: I am using a dictionary to store data for the various cities. See this for a basic introduction to dictionaries: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html . In the code that you are asking about, if there is already a dictionary entry for the city I am adding more data to that dictionary entry (which is itself a collection). If there isn't yet a dictionary entry for that city, I create a new collection to hold the data and create a new dictionary entry, with the city as the key and the collection the corresponding value.